# How to extract data from log_file.txt using bash

Tags: bash

i have a master_log_file.txt and the sequence is like below :

```
TransferDate|DeptID|FolderID             |DocID |AFPFileName|NoOfAcct| 
20181024    |1     |LRREM1.20181015.CGLOG|test  |xxxx       |12
20181024    |2     |LRREM2.20181013.CGLOG|home  |XyyX       |2
20181024    |3     |LRREM3.20181013.CGLOG|office|xy         |5
20181024    |4     |LRREM4.20181013.CGLOG|store |yy         |10
```

I want to create a bash file to separate all the log data according to the FolderID and DeptID into separated log file. Can someone give me an example on how to do this because i'm new with this batch thing. Thanks in advance.
Below is my bash file according to mjuarez suggestion.

```
echo off
for folder in `grep -v TransferDate log_test.txt | cut -d "|" -f3 | sort | uniq`; do 
   grep ${folder} separated.txt > F:/Work/FLP Code/test/folder_${folder}.txt; 
done
pause
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: Did you get this worked out?

Answer (score 1):

First, c.f. [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on showing what you've tried and generally making it worth the time for other people to feel you have done your due diligence.

Second: Is that format consistent? It's obviously formatted, so I'm going to assume it is.

```
cut -c 14-41 logFile | grep -v DeptID | sort -u |
  while read key
  do IFS="$IFS|" read dept folder <<< "$key";
     grep "$key" < logFile > $folder.$dept;
  done
```

14-41 is the range of the keys you mention, which I pull with `cut`.

Strip the header with `grep -v` and `sort -u` them to get a unique set of combinations defining each output file. Pipe that to a while read loop.

Add the pipe character for a temp assignment of $IFS to assign the department and folder to vars I use to create distinct filenames for your outputs, then `grep` the key for each combo to a relevant file.

Does that do what you need?

I see someone beat me to it, but I didn't assume the folder values were always consistent, since you mentioned dept separately.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your reply. Yes the folder name is consistent.

Comment: Working for you?

Answer (score 1):

Like you asked to separate all the log data according to the FolderID **and** DeptID, you can process the input file (let's call it **/tmp/log_file.txt**) this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

for key in $( cat /tmp/log_file.txt |sed -e 's/[ \t]//g;' |awk -F '|' '{print $2"_"$3}' |sort -u ); do
  fileName="$key"
  filter=$( echo "$key" |sed -e "s/\([^_]*\)_\(.*\)$/\1[ \t]*|\2/" )
  grep -re "$filter" /tmp/log_file.txt > "/tmp/$fileName"
done
```

Don't hesitate if you need further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can basically iterate over the unique elements you want to categorize (I used the `FolderID` column in this case), and send only those records to their own files, using grep.

```
for folder in `grep -v TransferDate file.txt | cut -d "|" -f3 | sort | uniq`; do 
   grep ${folder} file.txt > /tmp/folder_${folder}.txt; 
done
```

That creates the following files:

```
folder_LRREM1.20181015.CGLOG.txt  folder_LRREM3.20181013.CGLOG.txt
folder_LRREM2.20181013.CGLOG.txt  folder_LRREM4.20181013.CGLOG.txt
```

You can change the initial `grep` in the loop to use exactly the unique field or combination of fields you want.

**Updated:**

This is the finalized script, taking into account the two fields, and creating separate files for each of those categories:

```
for key in `cat file.txt | grep -v FolderID | awk 'BEGIN { FS="|"} { print $3 "_" $4 }' | sort | uniq` ; do
   value1=`echo $key | cut -d_ -f1`
   value2=`echo $key | cut -d_ -f2`
   grep -E "${value1}.*\|${value2}" file.txt > /tmp/key_${key}.txt;
done
```

It works a bit differently than the first one.  It needs to grep by both keys, but then inside the loop it needs to build a basic regexp to look for lines that match both of those values, and then send them all to a file that has the full key as part of its name.

Comment: Hi mjuarez, thanks for your reply. I have update my question. It would be great if you can reply to it. Thanks a lot.